# How to embed HTML in restructured text file?

Tags: html, embedded-resource, restructuredtext

I'm using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) and I'd like to add HTML encoding an interactive flash-type animation through the `<embed>` tag. From my .rst document, how can I specify the position of this arbitrary chunk of HTML?  Something like:

```
  .. html ::

  <embed>
  ... more html here ...
  </embed>
```

Does this feature exist?  thanks.

Answer (score 98):

Try

```
.. raw:: html

    <embed>
        ...
    </embed>
```

[The `raw` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through)