# Adding HTML in Blog Articles Written in RST Format in Pelican

Tags: python, restructuredtext, pelican

I am trying to get my hands on Pelican.

I need a feature, so that I can put some direct HTML files into the blog 
articles written in rst format. I also want those HTML files to be rendered.

The use case is like this: I want to show some html code and also how it looks like on the browser.

PS: I know how to attach code blocks, but this requirement is inverse of that, I want the HTML files to be actually rendered, rather than protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the HTML subheading to the raw directive and the content will be rendered.

```
.. raw:: html

    <p> I need a feature, so that I can put some direct HTML in the blog articles written in <b>rst</b> format. I also want those htmls to be rendered.</p>
```

See here:
[How to embed HTML in restructured text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621042/how-to-embed-html-in-restructured-text-file)

please note: there must be a newline between the `..raw::` directive and the actual raw html.