# How I can add attribute to img tag in Pelican

Tags: python, pelican

I want to add attribute to image tag in order to reference from JavaScript library as below.

```
<img src="img/sample.png" data-action="zoom">
```

However, I only can add alt, width, height as I know as below as outcome from Pelican.

```
<img alt="thumbnail" height="250px" src="/images/mech2.jpg">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Markdown (`.md`) file to create your article, then you can literally just include an image element with any attributes you like:

```
![This image is in Markdown format]({filename}/images/foo.png)

<img alt="This one is just a literal element" src="{filename}/images/bar.png" data-action="zoom" >
```

Would become:

```html
<p><img alt="This image is in Markdown format" src="../images/foo.png"></p>
<p><img alt="This one is just a literal element" src="../images/bar.png" data-action="zoom"></p>
```

---

For reStructuredText (`.rst`) articles, you can't do this; [per the documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#images) only a limited set of image options are supported*, and if you just try and include HTML inline it gets rendered out as-is:

```
.. image:: {filename}/images/foo.png
   :alt: this is an RST image directive

<img alt="This one is just a literal element" src="{filename}/images/bar.png" data-action="zoom">
```

Becomes:

```html
<img alt="this is an RST image directive" src="../../../images/foo.png">
<p>&lt;img alt="This one is just a literal element" src="{filename}/images/bar.png" data-action="zoom"&gt;</p>
```

** Specifically: `alt`, `height`, `width`, `scale`, `align`, `target`, `class` and `name`.*

Comment: Note however that you can include arbitrary html in restructuredText using the "raw" directive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621042/how-to-embed-html-in-restructured-text-file